# Google Places Api subway and train station search in Russia stopped working

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Till today the following query:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?language=ru&location=55.739216,37.547965&radius=1000&sensor=false&types=subway_station|train_station&key=xxxxxxxx

was result with 'Студенческая‎' , 'Studencheskaya' subway station in Moscow.

Today: ZERO_RESULTS

Answer (score 0):

This issue has already been reported on the Google Places API Issue Tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4061

Please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes, and to let us know you are interested in seeing it resolved.