# Google Places API subway_station, bus_station

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Places Api subway and train station search in Russia stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054629/google-places-api-subway-and-train-station-search-in-russia-stopped-working)

Few days ago I was testing (using) an application in which I  got the most nearest subway station using google places API,however yesterday and today I have been  testing again my application and now  I can´t get subway stations close to me.

I was reading  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/supported_types and google allows to use subway station type, when I use other types such as hospital, store and parks application  works!!!

I downloaded this -> http://github.com/brendannee/walksy

on Jscript file I wrote

```
placesService.search({
  radius: 4000
, location: trip.start
, types: [
  'train_station'
  , 'bus_station '
  , 'subway_station'
  ]
}
```

instead of

```
placesService.search({
  radius: 5000
, location: trip.start
, types: [
    'amusement_park'
  , 'aquarium'
  , 'bowling_alley'
  , 'casino'
  , 'cemetery'
  , 'city_hall'
  , 'embassy'
  , 'museum'
  , 'natural_feature'
  , 'park'
  , 'stadium'
  , 'zoo'
  , 'point_of_interest'
  ]
}
```

Can any one tellme what is my mistake?

thnaks a lot of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it might be because according to its Github page:

> For walking tours staring in San Francisco, the points of interest come from a google Fusion table with hand-picked points of interest in San Francisco, CA

Try picking a location outside of SF - it works for me. (maybe you should also add transit_station)

Answer (score 0):

I was testing with this :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?language=ru&location=4.647604837557583,-74.07900810241699&radius=1000&sensor=false&types=subway_station|train_station&key=xxxxxxxx

result:

`{ "html_attributions" : [], "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }`

I think that now google dont allow place service with subway station.

In other post somebody said:

[Google Places Api subway and train station search in Russia stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054629/google-places-api-subway-and-train-station-search-in-russia-stopped-working)

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has already been reported on the Google Places API Issue Tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4061

Please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes, and to let us know you are interested in seeing it resolved.