# Google Places API subway_station,?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

It is possible to get subway station info using google place API?

few weeks ago I did that, my tests were fine!, but now  testing doesn't work

google has changed access?

I was testing with this :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?language=ru&location=4.647604837557583,-74.07900810241699&radius=1000&sensor=false&types=subway_station|train_station&key=xxxxxxxx

result:

`{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}`

I think that now google dont allow place service with subway station.

In other post somebody said:

[Google Places Api subway and train station search in Russia stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054629/google-places-api-subway-and-train-station-search-in-russia-stopped-working)

thanks!!!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue has already been reported on the Google Places API Issue Tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4061

Please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes, and to let us know you are interested in seeing it resolved.